# How to generate n parameters/options in parameter-window?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I have the following code:

```
parameter Boolean Powerplant_on_Bus=true
    "Activate/Deactivate Conventional Energy Generation on Bus" annotation (
    Evaluate=true,
    HideResult=true,
    choices(__Dymola_checkBox=true),
    Dialog(group="Generation"));

  parameter Integer n[:]=
    "Number of Conventional Powerplants connected to the Bus"  annotation (
    Dialog(group="Generation", enable=Powerplant_on_Bus));
```

The result is this:
[Parameter Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpHFx.png)

With the following code I want to generate an option for choosing a profile table for the Powerplant in the paramter window:

```
replaceable model Powerplant_Profile =
      IntegraNet.HighVoltage.Basics.Tables.ElectricGrid.GenericPowerDataTable   "Load-profile data table for Powerplant Generation" annotation (choicesAllMatching=false,Dialog(tab="Powerplant",enable=Powerplant_on_Bus));
```

The result looks like this:
[Parameter Window "Powerplant"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd2xR.png)

My goal is to generate n options for choosing a powerplant-profile. For example: When I have choosen 5 Powerplants in the first parameter window in the field "n" I want to have 5 fields for choosing a profile in the parameter window "powerplant".

Thanks you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know dynamically changing the shown parameters directly in the parameter dialog is not possible currently in Dymola.

As a workaround - although I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need - there is the following way to do something similar.

```
package N_options
  package Data
    record Default "Default Record"
      parameter Real p1=1;
    end Default;

    record Data1 "Data set 1"
      extends Default(p1 = 2.3);
    end Data1;

    record Data2 "Data set 2"
      extends Default(p1 = 4.5);
    end Data2;
  end Data;

  record DataSelection
    parameter N_options.Data.Default data annotation (choicesAllMatching);
  end DataSelection;

  model MyModel
   parameter DataSelection vectorizedData[:];
  end MyModel;

  model MyExample
    MyModel myModel(vectorizedData={
      N_options.DataSelection(data=N_options.Data.Default()),
      N_options.DataSelection(data=N_options.Data.Data1()),
      N_options.DataSelection(data=N_options.Data.Data2())})
      annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}})));
  end MyExample;
end N_options;
```

This comes down to:

- A package containing your data
- An (intermediate) record where you can select which data you want to be able to choose
- A model containing the data as a `parameter`
- An example

Double-clicking the `myModel` in the example gives you the following dialog in Dymola:
[image: Parameter Dialog]

Clicking the 'Edit' button then shows:
[image: Sub-Dialog for parameter editing]

In the second dialog you can select the number of data-sets you want to use and which one should be chosen.